# How to pass **kwargs parameters to the relevant wrapped functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, variable-assignment, wrapper

I want to define a wrapper function that wraps up a number of other functions with many arguments and want to use the magic variables in the wrapper function.

For example, suppose I have these three functions:

```
def function1(ret, ben, period=0, **kwargs):
 return ret, ben, period


def function2(ret, ben, risk_free=0, **kwargs):
 return ret, ben, risk_free

def function3(ret, ben, rf=0, **kwargs):
 return ret, ben, rf
```

And I want to wrap these functions with another function and use the magic variables so I can keep track of all possible arguments that each function might take.

I have tried something like this:

```
def wrapper_function(ret, ben, **kwargs):

  out1 = function1(ret, ben, **kwargs)
  out2 = function2(ret, ben, **kwargs)
  out3 = function3(ret, ben, **kwargs)

  return out1, out2, out3
```

but this obviously fails because let's say, `function1` does not have the same arguments as, for example, `function2`.

For example, if I call the wrapper function with `wrapper_function(ret, ben, rf )` it will fail because `functions1` and `function2` don't have `rf` as their arguments.

My scope is essential to have a function that does something like this:

```
def wrapper_function(ret, ben, **kwargs1,**kwargs2,**kwargs3):

  out1 = function1(ret, ben, **kwargs1)
  out2 = function2(ret, ben, **kwargs2)
  out3 = function3(ret, ben, **kwargs3)

  return out1, out2, out3
```

This does not seem to work in python, however.

Any idea on how to use the magic variable in the wrapper function so no matter what arguments the functions inside it have it would work?

Comment: "this obviously fails" No, that should work. If it fails, you'll need to elaborate how.

Comment: @Sören I said why it fails 'functions don't have the same arguments', so If I call wrapper_function(ret, ben, rf ) it will fail because `functions1` and `function2` don't have `rf` as an argument.

Comment: right, sorry about that.

Comment: @Sören No worries. In any case, I found it useful to elaborate. Please let me know if you have any ideas.

Comment: "For example, if I call the wrapper function with wrapper_function(ret, ben, rf ) it will fail because functions1 and function2 don't have rf as their arguments." And even worse - they are missing one of *their* required arguments. Where do you imagine this argument comes from?

Comment: Good question. Assume that other arguments might have defaults set. so `rf = 0` or something.

Comment: What happens when two wrapped functions have the same kwarg arguments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of [`getfullargspec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getfullargspec), You can see what arguments your individual functions need, then get those from `kwargs` and pass them to the functions.

```py
def wrapper_function(ret, ben, **kwargs):
    fns = (function1, function2, function3)
    results = []

    for fn in fns:
        fn_args = set(getfullargspec(fn).args)
        fn_required_args = fn_args - {'ret', 'ben'}

        required_dict = {
            item: kwargs[item] for item in fn_required_args if item in kwargs
        }
        results.append(fn(ret, ben, **required_dict))

    return results
```

Here is a complete code for test:

```py
from inspect import getfullargspec


def function1(ret, ben, period=0):
    return ret, ben, period


def function2(ret, ben, risk_free=0):
    return ret, ben, risk_free


def function3(ret, ben, rf=0):
    return ret, ben, rf


def wrapper_function(ret, ben, **kwargs):
    fns = (function1, function2, function3)
    results = []

    for fn in fns:
        fn_args = set(getfullargspec(fn).args)
        fn_required_args = fn_args - {'ret', 'ben'}

        required_dict = {
            item: kwargs[item] for item in fn_required_args if item in kwargs
        }
        results.append(fn(ret, ben, **required_dict))

    return results


print(wrapper_function(10, 20, period=11, risk_free=22))
```

output:

```
[(10, 20, 11), (10, 20, 22), (10, 20, 0)]
```

---

**note**: If you don't want to hardcode this:

```py
fn_required_args = fn_args - {'ret', 'ben'}
```

You can get the `{'ret', 'ben'}` part, from this expression:

```py
set(getfullargspec(wrapper_function).args)
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is a way via introspection (the `inspect` module). Rough sketch below:

```
import inspect

def wrapper(ret, ben, **kwargs):
    fun1_argnames = inspect.getargspec(function1).args  # get valid args for function1
    theargs = {key: kwargs[key] for key in fun1_argnames}
    function1(**theargs)
```

However, this is getting a bit into 'hack' territory. I have never needed such a trick. I have a feeling that your problem could probably be solved in a different way (i.e. do you really need to wrap a huge amount of different functions with a huge amount of different arguments?)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you can just pick the relevant arguments out from the `kwargs` dict:

```
def wrapper_function(ret, ben, **kwargs):

    out1 = function1(ret, ben, kwargs['period'])
    out2 = function2(ret, ben, kwargs['risk_free'])
```

Of course, you may want to first check if they actually exist in the `kwargs`, e.g.

```
period = kwargs['period'] if 'period' in kwargs else 0
```

Answer (score -2):

This may be useful:

```py
function1(ret, ben, kwargs.get('period'))
...
```

Comment: how exactly this answer solves the problem?